# body inside express middleware is empty

Tags: node.js, express, mailgun

i'm receiving emails from mailgun so i set my endpoint as follow

```
app.post(
'http://www.example.com/mail',
async(req, res, next) => {
   // i want to check if email coming from mailgun
  // so i want to set if statement using the req.body['X-Mailgun-Coming']
  // which should be Yes
 // but i got empty body object
},
uploadHandler.any(),
comingEmails // but body in this function has the required data
)
```

as you can see i got empty body in the middle ware but in the main function, body has the required and i has access to this data

**note ==> this only happens when email has attachment**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`uploadHandler.any()` has to be BEFORE where you check `req.body` because it is that middleware that actually reads the body of the request and populates `req.body`.  So, you are trying to read `req.body` before the code runs that actually puts the value in it.

Here's how you would put it before you try to use req.body.

```
app.post(
    'http://www.example.com/mail',
    uploadHandler.any(),
    async(req, res, next) => {
       // i want to check if email coming from mailgun
       // so i want to set if statement using the req.body['X-Mailgun-Coming']
       // which should be Yes
       next();
    },
    comingEmails
);
```

Comment: thank you so much for your help, it actually works. i'd like to ask if there is another way to check if message coming from mailgun before the server actually handle the coming attachments

Comment: @hapi500 - That sounds like a different question so it might help to ask a new question.  You can start by examining the headers on the incoming request to see if there's anything unique about mailgun requests.  Headers are available before reading the body.